# Prepend a URL segment to a relative / relative to server URL

Tags: .net, regex

I have a requirement to prepend a URL segment to all relative, or relative-to-server URLs within an HTML document (eg href or src attributes) on a server-side application

I'm working in a .NET environment, and unfortunately there are no good base class libraries for loading a HTML string into a DOM and manipulating it (I also do not have the luxury of being able to introduce a third-party library at this point), so this seems like a good candidate for a regex replace, however this is something I'm a little weak on

I need a regex that can handle these two cases:

Relative to server URL:

`href="/controller/action"  -> href="/MyPathSegment/controller/action"`

Relative URL:

`href="image/logo.gif" -> href="/MyPathSegments/image/logo.gif"`

Don't worry about what `MyPathSegment` is ..I have logic elsewhere that can figure out the levels of path segments for relative URLs, I just want to focus on the regex problem

I figure I need a regex that can match on any `src="..."` or `href="/..."` pattern and insert my string at the beginning after the first opening double quote but am not experienced enough with regexs to figure this out.

Comment: What is this for/in? There are modules for Apache, for example, than can rewrite URLs on the fly.

Comment: This is in a standard .NET ASP.NET application hosted on IIS, in an environment over which I have no control over, alas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to find a URL, assert that the URL currently does NOT contain /MyPathSegment/, and replace it with the same property (href or src), and the same End-Of-URL, but in the middle, put your path segment:

```
(?<tag>(?:href|src)=")(?(?=/MyPathSegment/)(?!)|/?(?<url>[^"]*"))
```

Replace With:

```
${tag}/MyPathSegment/${url}
```

In VB.Net:

```
Dim strPathPrefix As String = "/MyPathSegment/"
Dim strTest As String = Regex.Replace("<a href=""/controller/action"" property=""something"">Hello World</a>", "(?<tag>(?:href|src)="")(?(?=" & strPathPrefix & ")(?!))/?(?<url>[^""]*"")", "${tag}/MyPathSegment/${url}")

strTest = <a href="/MyPathSegment/controller/action" property="something">Hello World</a>
```

Note that in the VB, I had to double the quotes.

With this use, whether or not you have a Slash currently would be irrelevant.  You'd just have to make sure that your strPathPrepend ends with "/"

Test it on some things and let me know if you hit any bumps that might require some tweaking.

[image: RegexBuddy Example]

```
(?<tag>...
```

The data following this should be captured into a capture group named "tag".

```
(?:href|src)
```

match Either "href" Or "src".  the "?:" means not to necessarily capture the results into that particular sub-expression, though the results WILL capture into the Parent sub-expression "tag"

```
=")
```

Capture equal sign and quote symbol literally, and close the capture group for "tag"

```
(?(...)...|...)
```

Example Conditional statement.  The IF is in the small sub-expression, the THEN is the left-side of the alternation "|", the ELSE is on the right-side of the alternation.

```
(?=...)
```

Example Lookaround.  In this case, the lookaround is a "Look-Ahead".  That means: Check if the text following the current position equals something, but don't advance the cursor.

```
(?(?=/MyPathSegment/)...
```

So, put our two examples together, and we get a conditional which says...    If, after collecting href=", we find /MyPathSegment/, then...

```
(?!)
```

This is another Lookaround.  It is a Negative lookahead.  But there is nothing in it.  Usually it would be (?!...).  Since it is a negative lookahead and it's empty, it automatically fails the Regex statement.  We WANT it to fail if it sees that your Path Segment is already in there.

```
|/?
```

Else, if /MyPathSegment/ was NOT found... optionally find a slash, but it isn't in a capture group.

```
(?<url>...
```

Also in the Else statement... After the optional slash, build our second capture group named "url"

```
[^"]*"
```

Capture anything that is NOT a Quote... Multiple times (optional, change * to + if you want to require something), then after catching everything that is NOT a quote... capture the quote into the "url" capture group also.

```
))
```

First closes the url capture group, then closes the conditional group.

Comment: If I test this in PowerShell with "<a href=`"/controller/action`"" -replace "((?:href|src)=`"(?(?=/MyPathSegment)(?!)))/?([^`"]*)`"", "$1/MyPathSegment/$2" I get back <a /MyPathSegment/ what I need to get back is <a href="/MyPathSegment/controller/action". I'm trying to prepend MyPathSegment, it should never be present at the start of a relative / relative to server URL. But you've given me some interesting ideas and helped me learn about back-references :)

Comment: I'm thinking the assert needs to be check if the URL does NOT begin with http:// or https:// since that would imply it was an absolute path URL, whereas a relative / relative to server URL could only begin with a letter (as part of a URL segment) or a / ?

Comment: I don't believe PowerShell allows conditionals in its regex engine.  If that's not it, may be something else.  It works in VB/C#.Net.

Comment: I updated the answer for use outside of the .Net framework.  With the way it is now, it should work on http://www.myregextester.com/index.php for testing (Be sure to Checkbox the .Net Framework option).  Still doesn't seem to work in PowerShell, which I still think is because of the conditional portion (?(?)).

Comment: Awesome - thanks so much! It works outside of PowerShell (the single quote was to escape the double quote). Looks like I have alot of reading to do, but could you briefly explain how what the ?:, ?= and ?! do?

Comment: BTW RegexBuddy is awesome :)

Comment: inorite?  I was doing Regex for a long time and just discovered it less than a year ago.  It's pretty convenient.